# Three.js - Turn of shadows on lighting

Tags: javascript, three.js, light

I have several 3D objects imported in json format that have been grooped to answer as one single object. Is there any way to light this object with NO shadows at all? I just want the object to be seen by ther user as clean as it gets.
Here is some code:

```
function initMesh(x, y, z) {
group = new THREE.Object3D();
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('vasi.js', function(geometry, materials) {
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    mesh.scale.x = x;
    mesh.scale.y = y;
    mesh.scale.z = z;
    mesh.opacity=1;
    var model = new THREE.Object3D();
    model.add(mesh);
    model.position.set(0,0,0);
    //mesh.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
    group.add(model);
});
loader.load('mikrespleures.js', function(geometry, materials) {
    mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    mesh1.scale.x = x;
    mesh1.scale.y = y;
    mesh1.scale.z = z;
    mesh1.opacity=1;
    var model1 = new THREE.Object3D();
    model1.add(mesh1);
    model1.position.set(0,0,0);
    //mesh1.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
    group.add(model1);
});
loader.load('megalespleures.js', function(geometry, materials) {
    mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    mesh2.scale.x = x;
    mesh2.scale.y = y;
    mesh2.scale.z = z;
    mesh2.opacity=1;
    var model2 = new THREE.Object3D();
    model2.add(mesh2);
    model2.position.set(0,0,0);
    //mesh1.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
    group.add(model2);
});
scene.add(group);}

function initLights() {
var light;  // A light shining from the direction of the camera.
light = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
light.position.set(0,100,10);
group.castShadow = false;
group.receiveShadow = false;
scene.add(light);
```

}

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the castShadow and receiveShadow flag to false.

```
function initMesh(x, y, z) {
group = new THREE.Object3D();
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('vasi.js', function(geometry, materials) {
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    mesh.scale.x = x;
    mesh.scale.y = y;
    mesh.scale.z = z;
    mesh.opacity=1;
    mesh.castShadow = false;
    var model = new THREE.Object3D();
    model.add(mesh);
    model.position.set(0,0,0);
    //mesh.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
    group.add(model);
});
loader.load('mikrespleures.js', function(geometry, materials) {
    mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    mesh1.scale.x = x;
    mesh1.scale.y = y;
    mesh1.scale.z = z;
    mesh1.opacity=1;
    mesh1.castShadow = false;
    var model1 = new THREE.Object3D();
    model1.add(mesh1);
    model1.position.set(0,0,0);
    //mesh1.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
    group.add(model1);
});
loader.load('megalespleures.js', function(geometry, materials) {
    mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    mesh2.scale.x = x;
    mesh2.scale.y = y;
    mesh2.scale.z = z;
    mesh2.opacity=1;
    mesh2.castShadow = false;
    var model2 = new THREE.Object3D();
    model2.add(mesh2);
    model2.position.set(0,0,0);
    //mesh1.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
    group.add(model2);
});
scene.add(group);
}

function initLights() {
var light;  // A light shining from the direction of the camera.
light = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
light.position.set(0,100,10);
group.castShadow = false;
group.receiveShadow = false;
scene.add(light);   
}
```

Comment: Hello Shreyas thanks for your effort! What you told me does not work in my code. I eddited my question so you can help me find what am i doing wrong.

Comment: I think you should apply the lines above not to the group but to meshes inside this group.